# how to generate only openapi schemas from java/kotlin data classes? (for vert.x based application)

Tags: java, kotlin, openapi, vert.x

I am trying to create an open API spec for an existing vert.x based application, and since there is no library to generate the open API spec automatically for vert.x based apis, I am wondering if there is a plugin or a tool that can help me generate at least the corresponding schemas for my data classes since I have a lot of them and it is really painful to manually create the corresponding schema for each one of them?

I am using kotlin and Jackson for serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no such library. Usually I would recommend to choose the reverse procedure which is to generate the model classes from your open api specification. For that, there is a really usefull library called [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator).

The additional advantage of this approach would be, that you can use a fully api-first approach by also using the Vert.x extension called [Web OpenAPI](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-openapi/java/)

Comment: unfortunately, I am trying to create the open API spec for an existing codebase, so Web OpenApi spec is not an option for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swagger java tools directly. Generation of swagger model from classes/annotations provides ***swagger-core*** library - see [github](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) or [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-core) repo.

If you for example have annotated method:

```
public interface EndPoints {
 @Operation(summary = "Delete product by ID ", method = "DELETE", operationId = "product/:deleteProductId",
    tags = {
      "Product"
    },
    parameters = {
      @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = "deleteProductId",
        required = true, description = "The ID for the Product", schema = @Schema(type = "string"))
    },
    responses = {
      @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Not found."),
      @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Product deleted."),
      @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error.")
    }
  )
  void deleteProduct();
}
```

you can generate API doc using following code:

```
Reader openApiReader = new Reader();
Operation operation = openApiReader.parseMethod(EndPoints.class..getDeclaredMethod("deleteProduct"), Lists.newArrayList(), null);
```

And for your specific use-case, if you want to only generate Schema for given class (and use it for example as request body or return value), you can do for example:

```
public class ErrorApiResponse {
  public String error;
  public String severity;
  public String message;
}

ResolvedSchema resolvedSchema = ModelConverters.getInstance()
    .resolveAsResolvedSchema(new AnnotatedType(ErrorApiResponse.class));
```

You can construct io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI manually, add generated Schemas to respective places. To construct JSON version of this API model, you simple call:

```
io.swagger.v3.core.util.Json.pretty(openAPI)
```